# Luggage transfer from Brisbane to Christchurch?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, bne

We will be traveling from Atlanta, GA to Christchurch, NZ via LAX and Brisbane via Delta Airlines and Virgin Australia.  I assume we will need to clear immigration.  Do we need to obtain our luggage and recheck or will the luggage go direct to the connecting flight to Christchurch?  How much time will we need to make the connection?

Comment: Likely depends on your ticket. Same ticket for both flights? Or separate bookings? If separate,  you'll definitely need to exit and get your bag, and re-check in.

Comment: If your bags are checked through you do not need to clear immigration.  Just head straight upstairs through security to the departures level.

Comment: Thank you.  We have booked our trip all on one itinerary!  Glad we won’t need to claim bags as we only have 2 hours to make connection!

Comment: Make sure that during check-in in Atlanta the bags are checked through to the final destination. Also note that on the way back, if you have the same itinerary you will have to go through passport control in LAX, pick up your bags, go through customs, drop your bags, and go through security.

Comment: Thanks, JCaron...I didn’t give any thought to the return and we have a quick connection!!

Answer (score 2):

Since you've bought a single ticket your luggage would be checked all the way to New Zealand. On the way back however you will have to pick up and re-check your luggage at LAX (as well as go through immigration) as the US doesn't allow seamless transit without presenting both yourself and your luggage to US immigration/customs.